# React Router V6: Don't want to show Header & Footer in App.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to display Header and Footer in other pages, except home page. I have an intro/loading page used "/" and home page used "/home". Can anyone help me?

```html
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <section>

        <Header />
        <main className="main-wrapper">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<PageIntro />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<PageHome />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<PageAbout />} />
            <Route path="/work" element={<PageWork />} />
            <Route path="/singlework/:id" element={<PageSingleWork />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<PageContact />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
          </Routes>
        </main>

        <Footer />
      </section>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing only `<Footer/>` and `<Header/>`

Make This change:

```
<header><Header /></header>
<footer><Footer/></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your router configuration code into two components one has routes with a header and the other has no routes with a header. For example,

> App.js

```
     <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<Layout />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/*" element={<DashboardMain />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

> Layout.js

```
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea should work fine. Format your code to resemble the one below.
Beware that CSS styles like `position: absolute` could affect how your browser serves your components - in my case, a login form had position of the parent `div` set to absolute so it was hindering the `footer` from being displayed even though it was rendered but the header was always present. Apart from that, this convection always works.
You can also use switch to determine if a user is signed in to render a different "Router" that has different routes.

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>

        <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<PageIntro />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<PageHome />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<PageAbout />} />
            <Route path="/work" element={<PageWork />} />
            <Route path="/singlework/:id" element={<PageSingleWork />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<PageContact />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
          </Routes>
        

        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use `exact` attribute for `<Route>` components

like this:

```
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<PageIntro />} />
            <Route exact path="/home" element={<PageHome />} />
            <Route exact path="/about" element={<PageAbout />} />
            <Route exact path="/work" element={<PageWork />} />
            <Route exact path="/singlework/:id" element={<PageSingleWork />} />
            <Route exact path="/contact" element={<PageContact />} />
            <Route exact path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
          </Routes>
```